# Which HTML 5 attributes, properties, and other stuff can degrade succesfully in non-supporting browsers?

Tags: html

Which HTML 5 attributes, properties, and other stuff can be degradable in non-supporting browsers, even without providing fallback?

**For example:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type here" />
```

In a non-supporting browsers the `placeholder` text will not show , which is ok to me.

Comment: What do you mean by “degradable”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the markup goes, pretty much everything degrades well in older browsers:

- The doctype triggers standards mode in all browsers
- The new elements display, albeit by default as inline elements (IE’s DOM issues with unknown elements notwithstanding)
- Unknown attributes don’t cause anything to break in browsers (like your `placeholder` example)
- The new form field types all display as text fields in browsers that aren’t aware of them

They tried to design HTML5 to work in existing browsers; see:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#backwards-compatible
- the “main philosophies” question in http://www.webstandards.org/2009/05/13/interview-with-ian-hickson-editor-of-the-html-5-specification/

The new JavaScript APIs obviously won’t work in older browsers, because they don’t exist there.